# Making a custom(/templated) ScrollViewer or ListBox that understands which item to bring to view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, scrollviewer, listboxitems

I am trying to make a panorama-like control in WPF c# that scrolls to/brings into view only one grid from a horizontal set of grids. I need to expose the command which allows me to scroll forward/backward from various controls (which using an InteractionTrigger would suffice) on any of the grids in the ScrollViewer or ListBox.

I want each of the internal grids to size to the actual height/width of the usercontrol they live in (like tiled pages), won't need any scrollbars, and will eventually be applying easing effects/states to each of the scroll positions.

If this is too vague/convoluted, please let me know.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution:

PathListBox. Downloaded the PathListBox toolkit (for the PathListBoxScrollBehavior), set the capacity to 1, and used the templated InteractionTriggers to bind various source objects on my grids to the InvokeCommandAction Increment/Decrement Commands. Then I added easing effects/GoToStateActions.

I realize this is sort of a cheat, but am still going to search for the "real" way to do this with custom control templates deriving from ListBox and/or ScrollViewer.